# Get by id from one model, items from another model using linq and relation one to many?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

There is two simple models with relation one to many.

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MessageModel> Messages { get; set; }

    public UserModel()
    {
        Messages = new List<MessageModel>();
    }
}

public class MessageModel
{
    public MessageModel()
    {
        this.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int? FromUserId { get; set; }
    public UserModel FromUser { get; set; }
}
```

I want to write a linq query from db, where I can by user id, get all message items.
I have tried something like this, but this not working.

```
UserModel userModel = db.UserModels.Where(x => x.Id == id(x.Messages)).ToList();

UserModel userModel = db.UserModels.Where(x => x.Id == id).Where(x => x.Messages).ToList();
```

I am looking for some decision or advice.

Comment: change your second Where to a Select :  db.UserModels.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => x.Messages).ToList();

Comment: @Riv  thanks, I`ve tried this, but not working, I have a redline mistake "Cannot implicity convert type List<MessageModel> to type UserModel".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var userMessages = db.UserModels.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(y => y.Messages).ToList();
```

Once you get the UserModel by ID, you need to select the Messages from it. And the return type is a List of MessageModel, not a UserModel

Comment: thank you, it`s working, I changed UserModel userModel, and write like you did var userMessages.